# View updating on last page in viewpager, not updating on current page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

Hi i am relatively new and learning Android.
I am stuck in using the viewpager here.

I want to show swipable pages and am doing so with the Fragmentstatepageradapter and viewpager. The structure of the pages is such that there are two dynamically created textviews in the top half and based on which is clicked some diff text should be displayed in the bottom half.

This is the mainactivity xml where viewpager is defined:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="12"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"/>
```

And this is the xml of the fragment_main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="12"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/main_container"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textviewdown"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The viewpager is creating swipable pages with the proper text view in the top half. And for the first page if i click on the text box, the lower textview is opening correctly.
But if i swipe to any other page and click on any of the textview the content is not updating in the same page, but updating in the same position of textviewdown on the previous page that i visited. I am not able to understand why.

Here is the code for the main fragment:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment

    public PageFragment(){
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        RelativeLayout mainContainer = (RelativeLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.main_container);
        final Activity activity = getActivity();

        TextView textview1 = (TextView) new TextView(activity);
        textview1.setText("Click for 1");
        textview1.setX(0);
        textview1.setY(0);
        textview1.setWidth(150);
        textview1.setHeight(50);
        textview1.setOnClickListener(clicktext1);
        TextView textview2 = (TextView) new TextView(activity);
        textview2.setText("Click for 2");
        textview2.setX(0);
        textview2.setY(150);
        textview2.setHeight(50);
        textview2.setWidth(150);
        textview2.setOnClickListener(clicktext2);
        mainContainer.addView(textview1);
        mainContainer.addView(textview2);
        return rootview;
    }

    View.OnClickListener clicktext1 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TextView textView3 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textviewdown);
            textView3.setText("This is article text");
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener clicktext2 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TextView textView3 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textviewdown);
            textView3.setText("This is diff text");
        }
    };
```

Here is the pageadapter code that i am using:

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new PageFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

And here is how it is called in the main activity:

```
ViewPager mViewpager2;

PageAdapter pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewpager2 = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager_main);
mViewpager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
mViewpager2.setAdapter(newspageAdapter);
```

I have already tried adding this and it is not working:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Also tried playing with the setoffscreenpagelimit value.

Answer (score 0):

Solved 
I had to make rootview a global variable and pass it to the onclick function and change the following

```
TextView textView3 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textviewdown);
```

to

```
TextView textView3 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.textviewdown);
```